# What is ''_'' in Verilog?

Tags: verilog, system-verilog, iverilog

I was viewing this code snippet:

```
module FD2 (d, cp, cd, q, qn);

  input d, cp, cd;
  output q, qn;

  nand #1   nand_2 (n2, d_, cp_),
            nand_3 (n3, n1, n4),
            nand_7 (q, n5, qn);

// SJM  nand #0   nand_1 (n1, d, cp_, cd),
  nand   nand_1 (n1, d, cp_, cd),
            nand_4 (n4, n2, n3, cd),
            nand_5 (n5, n3, cp),
            nand_6 (n6, n4, cp),
            nand_8 (qn, n6, cd, q);

// SJM not  #0   inv_1 (cp_, cp),
  not   inv_1 (cp_, cp),
            inv_2 (d_, d);

endmodule
```

What does "cp_" signify?

No where I could find answers, so I thought of posting here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code, `cp_` is the name of a signal, just like `cp` is the name of another signal.  The underscore has no special meaning in the name.  This is an example of a *simple identifier*.  Refer to IEEE Std 1800-2017, section 5.6 *Identifiers, keywords, and system names*:

> An identifier is used to give an object a unique name so it can be
> referenced. An identifier is either a simple identifier or an escaped
> identifier (see 5.6.1). A simple identifier shall be any sequence of
> letters, digits, dollar signs ( $ ), and underscore characters ( _ ).

It is legal to not declare signals explicitly, but it is a recommended good practice to do so.  It would be better to declare the signal using:

```
wire cp_;
```

The same is true for other signals which have not been declared, such as `d_`, `n1`, etc.

See also section 6.10 *Implicit declarations*.

Answer (score 3):

A underscore " _ " is legal character of any identifier and has no special meaning. But some people refer to the "_" character as "bar" meaning as if as you wrote `cp_` as

```
__
cp
```

meaning the *negation* of cp